# MathJax doesn't typeset two subscript-superscript combinations in a row

Tags: markdown, jekyll, mathjax, kramdown

I am at a loss in finding a more compact MWE, but MathJax 2.7.1 in Markdown with Jekyll and the Kramdown parser somehow typesets this with no problem:

```
${\langle s_j' \rangle}_{j=1}^{m-1}$
```

But when I place it two times in a row, it does not get typeset:

```
${\langle s_j' \rangle}_{j=1}^{m-1} {\langle s_j' \rangle}_{j=1}^{m-1}$
```

What is the error and how can I correct it?

I am using modified GitHub Pages template.

This is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'jekyll'
gem 'jekyll-paginate'
gem 'kramdown'                                                                                                        
gem 'pygments.rb'
```

This is my `mathjax_support` include file:

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
  MathJax.Hub.Config({
    TeX: {
      equationNumbers: {                                                                                              
        autoNumber: "AMS"
      }
    },
    tex2jax: {
      inlineMath: [ ['$','$']],
      displayMath: [ ['$$','$$'] ],
      processEscapes: true,
    }
  });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.1/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML"></script>
```

Comment: There's not enough information. Are you using markdown?

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger Yes I am using markdown, I added more details.

Comment: It is indeed a duplicate, thanks! I will close it. Did not expect the problem to originate in kramdown.